# Make new form appear in the center of the other form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have code like follows that on pressing a button on form, a new form appears. To make this new form appear in center of the already existing form I have tried to set ‘**Start Position**’ property of new form but still it is not appearing in the center. What can I do ? any help is really appreciated. Thanks

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myExample diag = myExample.Create();
    diag.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you show what Create does and how StartPosition is set?

Answer (score 0):

This is from my program actually running it's as answered by @Notronic.

```
  private void GetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Form MatiereForm = new Form();
      MatiereForm.Width = this.Width -100;
      MatiereForm.Height = this.Height - 100;
      MatiereForm.Parent = this.Parent;
      MatiereForm.Text = "Les Matieres";
      MatiereForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
      MatiereForm.Show();
    }
```

Event your form is static you must make a new instance for your form.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myExample diag = new myExample();
     diag.Parent = this.Parent;
     diag.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
     diag.ShowDialog();
}
```